# How to configure hubot for campfire in UNIX?

Tags: hubot

I am trying to deploy to Heroku, using foreman. How to configure hubot for campfire in UNIX?

I have already tried:

```
% bin/hubot -a campfire
```

This error out Error message being

> 'campfire' is not recognised as a hubot command.